# Rails 4: ActiveRecord-style I18n on a non-ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-i18n

I have a Plain Old Ruby Class (PORO) that behaves a lot like an ActiveRecord model, although it is not persisted to the database.

To make the internationalization(I18n) as painlessly as possible, I would like to also use the `SomeModel.model_name.human` and `SomeModel.human_attribute_name(:attribute)` methods on this PORO.

What module do I need to include to include above methods on my PORO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend your class with the `ActiveModel::Translation` module:

```
class Widget
  extend ActiveModel::Translation
end

Widget.model_name.human
=> "Widget"

Widget.human_attribute_name :my_attribute
=> "My attribute"
```

Comment: I had to overwrite `self.i18n_scope` on the Widget class to return `:activerecord` otherwise it would look for the translations under the `:activemodel` key

Comment: I had to do the same in Rails 7, @Glenn.